# How do I bind a key in OSX to open a new window of an application?

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces

I can't find a way to do this. There's only binding to open an application. But the apps I want to use this on, (chrome, terminal, and finder) are always open. I just want to open a new window in the current work space.

I can <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> then hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. But <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> can change my workspace if a window of that app is already opened in another work space.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single way to open a new window with AppleScript, but `make new window` or `make new document` works in many applications.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    make new window
    activate
end tell    
tell application "Finder"
    make new Finder window
    activate
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ""
    activate
end tell
tell application "TextEdit"
    make new document
    activate
end tell
```

You can [assign shortcuts to scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) with applications like FastScripts or Alfred.

You can also open new windows from the Dock:

[image]